# MongoDB find query RangeError

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB find query to fetch data from collection.but it gave me the following error:

> RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: Attempt to write outside buffer bounds
>       at Buffer.write (buffer.js:922:13)

Any idea why this error coming? and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078342/mongodb-rangeerror-attempt-to-write-outside-buffer-bounds

Comment: I have checked the size of my find query. by using the following code: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(query)).length and itis giving me result  15000104 bytes .which is less than 16mB

Comment: I am using find query with $nin here

Comment: If you try to run a `.find()` query and the sum size of returned documents is > 16 mb, you might get this error. You can work around it by using `.limit()` to limit the number of returned results.